# Customize Windows 7 window and file manager to be more Linux-like

Tags: windows-7, linux

Can I configure my Windows 7 system to make it behave much more like Linux? The goal is to use only Windows kernel and drivers.

I want to change the following Windows aspects:

- Window manager, for example, to openbox
- File manager
- Add some useful GUI features, panels, docks, for example, cairo-docks, tint2

If you tried this I will appreciate your comments about what did you also change in Windows to make it more customizable and flexible. Are there any projects or guides that explain how to do that?

Comment: Back in the day, you could try out Win XPLite which was a package that would strip down Windows XP to a minimal and annoying run environment. You might be interested in vLite which is supposed to do the same for Windows 7, but most people in this day of VM environments, install something like VirtualBox (its free) and run the best of both worlds by installing Linux as a VM on Windows 7 or vise versa.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Windows and Linux are fundamentally different.

However, there products like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Cygwin is a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows as well as acts as a Linux API layer providing substantial Linux API functionality.

FYI, Cygwin is free and open source.

Comment: Yep, Cygwin is a bit awkward and far from perfect, but it does give you access to many *nix tools.

Comment: I dont know about awkward, but there are a lot of people who swear by it.

Comment: Question was clarified by the OP, so I guess Cygwin is not what they wanted after all.